# Inner Proxies with Selenium

Tags: java, webdriver, proxy-classes

*Preface:  While this question includes a lot of WebDriver terminology, it's really a Java proxies question, which I am still trying to wrap my head around.  If you don't understand WebDriver, skip down, and I'll post a simplified problem*

I currently have a wrappers around `WebElement` and `List<WebElement>`, namely `EnhancedWebElement` and `WebElementList`.  It is for quite a few reasons, and has allowed me quite a bit of flexibility.  I also use the page object pattern, and declare all of my elements as the two wrappers I have created (which works great).

However, I recently asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17818074/how-to-return-a-lazily-instantiated-dynamic-webelement).   I wanted to find an element within an element, and still keep the entire thing within a proxy.  The answer worked great, and I made it generic and put it in my `EnhancedWebElement` class.  It looks like this:

```
public EnhancedWebElement findEnhancedWebElement(final By by){
        return (EnhancedWebElement) Proxy.newProxyInstance(this.getClass().getClassLoader(), new Class<?>[] { WebElement.class }, new InvocationHandler() {
            // Lazy initialized instance of WebElement
            private EnhancedWebElement webElement;

            public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args)
                    throws Throwable {
                if (webElement == null) {
                    webElement = new EnhancedWebElement(findElement(by), driver);
                }
                return method.invoke(webElement, args);
            }
        });
    }
```

However...this has one problem.  If I find an **element within an element within an element**, I lose the first proxy.  This is because it instantiates the element in order to perform the next `findEnhancedWebElement()` function.

While you may think my crazy, my goal is to have a set of functions so I could do something like this:

```
EnhancedWebElement newElement = element.findElements(By.foo).getElementFoundBy(By.bar).findElement(By.foobar);
```

and still not performed *any* selecting on the page until I do `newElement.click()` or whatever action on the element.

*(If you are really wondering why, it is because I have quite a few functions in `EnhancedWebElement` and `WebElementList` that depend on it not being instantiated.  If I was just going to perform a click(), then I wouldn't need all this)*

*For all people that don't understand WebDriver.  I have Object X.  It has a function that can return another object X, but only after doing some processing.  Object X also has other functions.  If I do `X someObject = new X().getX().getX().getX()`, I don't want any of the processing to be done until I do `someObject.otherFunction()`*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  I needed to create a proxy around the original WebElement, not the new EnhancedWebElement, and then create a new instance of EnhancedWebElement wrapped around it.  That way, when I am using the findEnhancedWebElement(), I never touch the original WebElement.